# how use object.filter and calculate all integerfiled

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have django(2.0) models : product and vendor_name

```
class vendor_name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='name vendor', max_length=256)
    version = models.CharField(verbose_name='version vendor', max_length=256)

class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='name product', max_length=256)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(vendor_name, verbose_name='vendor', 
blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    lic = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='lic', default=0)
```

Example___

first record:

```
product.name = AAA
vendor.name = ZOO
vendor.version = 6
lic = 27
```

second record:

```
product.name = BBB
vendor.name = ZOO
vendor.version = 6
lic = 500
```

how use object.filter where vendor.name ZOO and vendor.version 6, calculate all product lic ?

I want see: 527 and I add a new record

```
product.name = CCC
vendor.name = ZOO
vendor.version = 6
lic = 500
lic = 1027
```

and I do not export site `{{ product.lic }}` but why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/) for this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
product.objects.filter(vendor__name='zoo', vendor__version=6).aggregate(lic_total=Sum('lic'))
```

Result:

```
{'lic_total': 527}
```

Note to filter by foreignkey related object's field you should use double underscore [`__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your advice has helped.